# Should I Use a Comma or a Semicolon at the End of a Series of Complex Introductory Phrases or Dependent Clauses?

Tags: commas, prepositional-phrases, semicolons, dependent-clause, adverbials

In my writing, I begin several sentences with a series of two or three -- or more -- adverbial (or prepositional) phrases (or dependent clauses), some of which contain commas. Seeking clarity, in order to separate each item in this complex series from the others, I utilize the semicolon. Do I need to use a semicolon after the last introductory phrase (or clause) too, separating it from the main meat of the sentence, or may I simply use a comma to separate the last introductory phrase (or clause) from the independent clause(s)? I wish to create a clear separation between my series of complex introductory adverbial (or prepositional) phrases (or dependent clauses) and the actual heart of my sentence, but I am not sure what the rule is here. The use of a semicolon may give briefly my readers the false impression the series is continuing; however, a comma may not be strong enough to demarcate the introductory material from the sentence's core. Is a comma -- or is a semicolon -- best after a complex (i.e., comma-rich) series of introductory phrases (or clauses)?

In the following example, should there be a comma or a semicolon after *car*?

1. Knowing she had to get to the store before it closed in fifteen minutes because she needed to buy bacon, eggs, and pancake mix; afraid of having to walk by -- yet again -- the extremely aggressive pit bull chained to her new neighbor's front yard oak; dreading having to do battle with her unreliable, twenty-five-year-old car, she took a deep breath, opened the front door, and exited her bungalow.

or

2. Knowing she had to get to the store before it closed in fifteen minutes because she needed to buy bacon, eggs, and pancake mix; afraid of having to walk by -- yet again -- the extremely aggressive pit bull chained to her new neighbor's front yard oak; dreading having to do battle with her unreliable, twenty-five-year-old car; she took a deep breath, opened the front door, and exited her bungalow.

Comment: Could you provide a sample passage?

Comment: I just provided an example of the kind of issue I'm facing. I hope it helps.

Comment: While this site is not going to address poetry, your poem opens with such excitement that you could make the artistic decision without regard to propriety. Consider that your stream of consciousness flows freely, while a semicolon is bookish. Periods would be cleaner, and shocking.